# Unable to close Established db connections

Tags: linux, tcp

iam running my application in Linux server, when it is running there are almost 100's of connections are getting established and not getting close.

```
   tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57094 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57088 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57100 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57104 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57118 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57112 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57129 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57142 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57136 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57148 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57154 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57166 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57160 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57172 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57178 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57190 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57184 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57196 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57202 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57214 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57208 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57220 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57226 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57238 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57232 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57244 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57250 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57262 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57256 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57268 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57274 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57286 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57280 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57292 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57298 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57310 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57304 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57316 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57322 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57334 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57328 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57340 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57070 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57076 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 s233683dc4v133.ushrnd:57082 10lxgrcqadb01.qa-p:ncube-lm ESTABLISHED
```

How to find where these established connections are getting and how to handle to close?

Comment: What is the real or perceived problem with open connections? And how should we know how to close them, you didn't mention the RDBMS you're using, how those connections come about, whether you have control over how they get established ...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can run netstat with -p flag to watch the program to which each connection belong